# Adjoint of the derived group

Tags: number-theory, algebraic-geometry, algebraic-groups, arithmetic-geometry, reductive-groups

Firstly, let $G$ be a nice linear algebraic group (for instance connected reductive group) over $\mathbb{Q}$. I shall first define the two other groups I require

> $\textbf{Definition:}$ If $Z(G)$ is the center of the group $G$, then we define the adjoint group of $G$, denoted by $G^{\operatorname{ad}}$, to be the quotient $G/Z(G)$.

> $\textbf{Definitoin:}$ The derived subgroup of $G$, denoted by $G^{\operatorname{der}}$, is the intersection of all normal subgroups $N$ of $G$ such that $G/N$ is commutative.

Is $G^{\operatorname{ad}}=(G^{\operatorname{der}})^{\operatorname{ad}}$?

I ask this because it seems to be true for $G=\operatorname{GL}_n$, where $G^{\operatorname{der}}=\operatorname{SL}_n$ and $(G^{\operatorname{der}})^{\operatorname{ad}}\cong G^{\operatorname{ad}}\cong \operatorname{PGL}_n$ and also for $G=\operatorname{GSp}_{2n}$, where $G^{\operatorname{der}}=\operatorname{Sp}_{2n}$ and $(G^{\operatorname{der}})^{\operatorname{ad}}\cong G^{\operatorname{ad}}$.

My question comes because I am trying to understand Shimura varities. If $(G,X)$ is Shimura datum, and $X^+$ is a connected component of $X$, then $(G^{\operatorname{der}},X^+)$ is a connected Shimura datum. This clearly requires the two of them to have the same adjoint group, but I am not sure why this is true.

A proof or any reference of one, will be a great help. If in fact the answer is 'no', then I might need to find some other reason why a connected component of a Shimura datum is a connected Shimura datum.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The statement $(G^{der})^{ad}=G^{ad}$ is equivalent to $G=Z(G).G^{der}$. This is 17.42 of Milne's book *Reductive Groups*.

---

Per Coherent Sheaf's request: $G=Z(G).G^{der}$ is equivalent to the natural map $G^{der}\to G^{ad}$ being surjective. Of course, equivalently, $(G^{der})^{ad}\to G^{ad}$ is surjective. Thus, all we need to know is that $(G^{der})^{ad}\to G^{ad}$ is injective.

The kernel is exactly $(Z(G)\cap G^{der})/Z(G^{der})$, so we need to know $Z(G^{der})=Z(G)\cap G^{der}$, i.e., that $Z(G^{der})\subset Z(G)$. But this again follows from the equality $G=Z(G).G^{der}$!

Comment: I am probably missing something very silly. Is it obvious that these two statements are equivalent?

Comment: I think I understand why they are equivalent. This clearly implies that $Z(G^{\operatorname{der}})=G^{\operatorname{der}}\cap Z(G)$. Isn't it? Thanks a lot